# linux: question marks in file status; cannot stat file

Tags: linux, stat

Linux 2.6.18-164.11.1.el5.centos.plus
filesystem in question: reiserfs

Hi,

I'm having trouble deleting a file:

```
[root@flat: all_subjs_wcbf]# ls -lah
total 0
drwxrwxrwx 2 szhu cfn 88 Sep  1  2011 ./
drwxrwxrwx 3 szhu cfn 80 Jun  8  2011 ../
?--------- ? ?    ?    ?            ? sub13_AVG_5_cbf.m

[root@flat: all_subjs_wcbf]# rm sub13_AVG_5_cbf.m 
rm: cannot lstat `sub13_AVG_5_cbf.m': Permission denied
```

Looking at other posts on serverfault and stackoverflow for suggestions:

- the dir and containing dir's all have executable permission set, for all users. I've tried setting all containing dirs to 777 again at the same time just in case, but still cannot lstat.
- there are no associated IO errors reported.

I've tried "rm -rf" and "rm -i" just in case. No luck.

I'll eventually pull the disk offline and check it, but want to put that off because it's heavily used. So if this is not a disk error and can be fixed now, it'd be a great help! Thanks.

-Michael

Comment: See anything interesting in `dmesg`?

Comment: Nothing I can see in `dmesg`, `/var/log/dmesg` or even `/var/log/messages`. I'm pretty new to all this so I could be missing something, but not too likely.

Answer (score 1):

This *is* a disk error, and you will need to take the disk offline and check it with `reiserfsck`.

Comment: OK, I'll take it down as soon as I can and let you know what `reiserfsck` comes up with.